# 100D dioptric adjustment

Tags: canon, viewfinder, diopter

I was playing a bit with my dioptric adjustment and found out that I see best with that being set to the lowest value.
How is this possible? My eyesight is probably nearly perfect and I would definitely know if it was -3.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you actually are seeing best when it is set to the other end of the adjustment range: +1 diopter. Just as someone can have 20/20 distance vision and need reading glasses with a positive diopter to see things that are close, even if you have 20/20 or better distance vision your eyes may no longer be able to relax enough to focus on very near objects.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you mean by  your eyesight being "probably nearly perfect."  Do you have the results of an actual eyetest?  It's quite possible you've got a little myopia (near-sightedness).

Next, the diopter adjustment may well be a bit off, especially if you're holding the camera even a bit closer or farther from your eye than the baseline calibration is set for.

BTW, for those who care :-),  "diopter" is the inverse of the focal length of a lens.  A lens of -3 diopters has a focal length of -3.33 meters.

Comment: Probably nearly perfect = don't wear glasses, see quite well